# Can not update Bash on Debian 6.0 (Squeeze)

Tags: linux, debian, bash

I can not update [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) on a Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) server to get rid of the discovered vulnerability:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

apt-get update
apt-get install bash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
bash is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Can I use Squeeze-LTS for this server just to update Bash? After one week I will be on another server, so I will not make any other updates.

```
uname -m
x86_64

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.5
Codename:       squeeze
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must use the `squeeze-lts` repository in order to continue receiving updates to Debian Squeeze

To add this repository, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the line

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main non-free contrib
```

(you can remove `non-free` and `contrib` if desired)

Note that as of this instant, `squeeze-lts` only has the updated bash for the original [CVE-2014-6271](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271) but has not yet updated to fix the new [CVE-2014-7169](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-7169).

To update only bash, after running `apt-get update` use `apt-get install bash` to install just bash, instead of a complete upgrade.

Comment: When I do so, my bash keeps stuck at 4.1.5(1) release and remains vulnerable...

Answer (score 3):

I had to add LTS repositories to update bash which fixes the Shellshock vulnerability on Debian Squeeze. I hope someone else finds this useful:

First, check to see if your box is vulnerable. Cut/paste this to your command line:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo "WARNING: SHELLSHOCK DETECTED"' \
bash --norc -c ':' 2>/dev/null;
```

If you get a response like:

```
WARNING: SHELLSHOCK DETECTED
```

As I did in Squeeze, you have the vulnerability. You'll have to update your repositories to the LTS version to get the updates, by commenting out your current repository lines starting with 'deb' in your /etc/apt/sources.list file and then adding these:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Now you should update your local cache and install the upgraded bash (their servers are slow now because everyone's updating, so just pull down the bash one for bandwidth's sake):

```
apt-get update && apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

You can do a full system upgrade later. Now run the vulnerability check script above and you shouldn't get any text output, which means you're patched :)

Answer (score 1):

I've already updated every Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) system I have access to, to Debian 7 (Wheezy), which was surprisingly mostly painless.

If you can't do that, there do seem to be updates in Squeeze-LTS; it has a copy of Bash with yesterday's date, 4.1.3+deb6u1.

Comment: I believe that should be 4.1-3+deb6u2, might have updated since you wrote that.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) is not supported anymore. See the [Debian Security Announcement](https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2938) for the reasons.

If you want to have security updates you need to change your `sources.list`. This is what you need to enter:

> cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep lts
>
> deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
>
> deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free

This only works for x86 and x64.

So you **have to do** the following (quoting the wiki):

For binary packages, add this line:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

For source packages, add this line:

```
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Obviously you can decide which package types you want to include.

See this for details on the version you should have once updated:

[Debian Security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/bash)

Source: [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using)